# How to rewrite this url using htaccess in php?

Tags: php, html

I have this URL : http://website.com/?b=jack&s=TomJery&c=Stick

and wanted to rewrite it to : http://website.com/jack/TomJery/Stick

How to do this using the htaccess or without .htaccess in php

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
www.example.com/username
```

can be translated, using .htaccess to

```
www.example.com/viewuser.php?user=username
```

then in the viewuser.php you can use the variable `$_GET['user']` which will have the value `username`. From there, your script can retrieve whatever information you want to show based on these values.

the .htaccess needed will be

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)$ viewuser.php?user=$1
```